# Commitment fulfilled before public beta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, private-beta, commitment-fulfillment

Today I got this email cited below, saying that I fulfilled my commitment to the new Cryptography Stack exchange site. I also got the [bonus reputation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/33091/palo-ebermann?tab=reputation) and [upholder badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/210/upholder?userid=33091) on Area51.

As I understood before, the commitment can be fulfilled earliest with the second day of public beta, but the site is still in private beta (a bit longer than normal, for not enough questions). It would be the second day of public beta now if it would have gone with the original plan, though.

Is this simply an error, e.g. this script calculating the commitments was not informed about the longer private beta period? Or is there something wrong in the FAQ?

I committed to **post at least 3 questions and answer any that I can during the beta period**, if I remember right - I have two questions now (9 answers). From the [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography), it seems that 3 people have fulfilled their commitment. [Thomas Pornin](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/30993/thomas-pornin) has only one question (but 27 answers, most quite good, which may balance out), while [Tangurena](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/22700/tangurena) had no questions at all (11 answers).

> Thank you for following through on your commitment to Cryptography!
>
> In the 8 days since Cryptography launched, the community has generated
>   52 questions (51 answered!), 128 answers, 179 users, and 82 views per
>   day.
>
> Please share a link to the site with anyone you think might be
>   interested in our community:
>
> http://crypto.stackexchange.com
>
> We hope you continue to visit Cryptography and help it grow into a
>   vibrant, useful community that benefits the internet at large.
>
> All the best,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team
>
> p.s. Now that you've followed through on your commitment, you can
>   commit to an additional site proposal! Check out the list at
>   http://area51.stackexchange.com.

Also, if this mail is really meant to be sent while still in private beta, the *Please share a link* seems not really appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, our commitment fulfillment logic was incorrect: it mishandled sites with longer-than-normal private betas. This is fixed now; thanks for the report.